# Best approach on replicating configuration settings on load balanced sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, replication

This is a rather general question but I'm trying to assess what best approach to take when it comes to deploying SharePoint solutions onto load balanced environments.

Let's assume we have the following:

WebServer-01 and WebServer-02

Our SharePoint installation is balanced over these two environments, but as a developer, I only have access to WebServer-01 for deployment. The assumption here is that the infrastructure guys set up a replication from 01 to 02 but did not set up a replication for configuration files.

What would be the best, out of experience, approach to replicate the configuration file to the second server, without tweaking the replication script or logging into the box?

I was thinking of creating a deployment package, for example click-once that injects the required appSettings, but this in itself is risky?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy everything the 'SharePoint way', as in [building WSP packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466225%28v=office.12%29.aspx), then there is no need to manually replicate settings across multiple servers in the same Farm. SharePoint takes care of it.

You may want to consider posting SharePoint related questions on [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)

Some further helpful tips

- [SharePoint Development Guidelines](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/05/muhimbis-sharepoint-development.html).
- [Creating a Solution Package in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466225%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Creating a SharePoint Solution Package (.wsp) in 5 steps](http://geekswithblogs.net/evgenyblog/archive/2008/01/27/118966.aspx)
- [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/).